# After playing my game once, if i select it again from the main menu it instantly cuts to the game over screen (pygame)

Tags: python, function, pygame

Basically whenever i select my game from the main menu it will play, but then if i go back to the main menu and select it again, it just shows the game over screen, and wont play again.

In the code below its about the zy_mainloop() part of the main_menu that doesnt run after the first time. I'd really appreciate some help with this

```
def main_menu():
    WIDTH = 1280
    HEIGHT = 800
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

    main_menu = True
    while main_menu:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                    WIDTH = 480
                    HEIGHT = 600
                    pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
                    g.new()
                    g.show_go_screen()
                    main_menu = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_2:
                    zy_mainloop()
                    main_menu = False


        screen.blit(mainmenu_img, mainmenu_rect)
        pygame.display.flip()


def start_screen():
    WIDTH = 1280
    HEIGHT = 800
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

    start_screen = True
    while start_screen:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                    main_menu()
                    start_screen = False

        screen.blit(startscreen_img, startscreen_rect)
        pygame.display.flip()

def game_over_noscore():
    WIDTH = 1280
    HEIGHT = 800
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    screen.blit(gameovernoscore_img, noscore_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()

    gameover_screen = True
    while gameover_screen:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                    main_menu()
                    gameover_screen = False

def zy_mainloop():
    WIDTH = 480
    HEIGHT = 600
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    zy_running = True

    while zy_running:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                zy_running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and zyplayer.shotsfired <= 1:
                    zyplayer.shoot()

        # Update
        zy_all_sprites.update()

        # Hit Check
        hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(zy_bullets, zy_enemybullets, True, True, pygame.sprite.collide_circle)
        for hit in hits:
            m = zyEnemyBullet()
            zy_all_sprites.add(m)
            zy_enemybullets.add(m)
            zyplayer.shotsfired -= 1

        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(zyplayer, zy_enemybullets, True, pygame.sprite.collide_circle)
        for hit in hits:
            zyplayer.lives -= 1
            m = zyEnemyBullet()
            zy_all_sprites.add(m)
            zy_enemybullets.add(m)
        hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(zy_bullets, zy_enemies, True, False, pygame.sprite.collide_circle)
        for hit in hits:
            zy_enemy.enemylives -= 1
            zyplayer.shotsfired -= 1
        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(zyplayer, zy_enemies, False, pygame.sprite.collide_circle)
        for hit in hits:
            zyplayer.lives -= 3

        # Win / Lose condition
        if zyplayer.lives == 0:
            game_over_noscore()
        if zy_enemy.enemylives == 0:
            game_over_noscore()

        # Draw
        zy_drawgame()
```

Comment: I imagine you're not resetting one of the two variables determining the win/lose condition, but I can't see where you even set these in the first place. Where do you instantiate the player's lives?

Comment: Theyre in other classes, this is not the entirety of my code, i tried resetting it by setting the lives back to the original values (3 & 5) but it didn't have any effect

Comment: Hmm... I don't know if this is the cause but in your game_over_noscore function you need to swap the call to main_menu() and the gameover_screen=False otherwise it won't change the gameover_screen variable until after you've exited the menu and all its subroutines. Could be part of the problem?

Comment: Tried that as well, still the same problem :/

Comment: (you should also call the clock.tick method on the main and menu screens: no need to run at 100% of the CPU to display a static image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not seem code doing multiple windows, depending on the pygame.QUIT event, and then calling pygame.display.set_mode again before.

Maybe the "QUIT" event is persisting across function calls? 
I'd suggest you to prefix each  `pygame.display.set_mode`  call in there with a `pygame.event.get()` - that would flush pending events, and ensure no events from a previous screen are on queue.

Looking back at your code - how does calling `game_over_noscore()` makes your program exit the mainloop? Or it does not, and only keeps displaying things until the player closes the window?

Comment: i dont think it does and i think thats where the main problem lies, but the problem with that is that i dont know how to make it exit the mainloop? Because i think the issue is that when from the menu it plays zy_mainloop() it just continues where it was which is at the gameover screen

Comment: I like to use Exceptions in pygame, so that verifications at arbitrary function depths can ensure that a scene is transitioned (for example, from game play to game-over screen) in a higher level.

You put the the call to the mainloop inside a try...except statement, and raise your "GameOver" exception in the verification functions. This should help you get a grasp on this pattern, although it is quite straightforward: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/user-defined-exception